# Piping concatenated Gulp stream file.contents to server (connect, express or http) response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp

I suspect this comes from a limited understanding of streams but I've looked everywhere and cannot get it to work. In short, I want to take a Gulp stream and pass the concatenated contents of the stream to an express response directly **without** writing to the file system.

This is how I got the idea (which works fine):

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
    stream.pipe(res);
});
```

But I want to apply the same concept using a Gulp stream:

```
app.get('/app/js/concatenated-js-files.js', function(req, res){
    gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat())
        .pipe(res);
});
app.listen(5555, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 5555');
});
```

Which does not work and yields the following when requesting `/app/js/concatenated-js-files.js` from the browser:

```
[gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-concat': Missing fileName option for gulp-concat
    at module.exports (/Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/gulp-concat/index.js:10:24)
    at Object.handle (/Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/index.js:83:15)
    at next_layer (/Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at /Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:213:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:12)
    at next (/Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:207:19)
    at Layer.expressInit [as handle] (/Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:23:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:255:15)
    at /Users/lgomez/Projects/index-packager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:216:9
```

That error is expected. [gulp-concat](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat/blob/master/index.js) was written to output to file.

I'd like to avoid writing a gulp plugin that would be very similar to gulp-concat. I may fork and suggest it but, for now, is there another way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Here's the complete code if you'd like to try it.

```
var express = require('express');
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var concat  = require('gulp-concat');
var app     = express();
app.get('/app/js/concatenated-js-files.js', function(req, res){
    gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat())
        .pipe(res);
});
app.listen(5555, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 5555');
});
// http://localhost:5555/app/js/concatenated-js-files.js
```

Comment: **Note:** I have tried [event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream), [bufferstreams](https://github.com/nfroidure/BufferStreams) and [kat](https://github.com/fent/node-kat) but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gulp` works on streams of virtual File objects, not physical files. As such, `gulp-concat` doesn't write to the file system no matter what name you give it. However, you will still have a problem because you cannot send these file objects directly to the `res` response.

You need to write the *contents* of the virtual file(s) to `res`. An easy way to do this is to use `through` to make a stream that reads the gulp input and writes the files' contents to `res`. If your stream handles multiple files, then you don't need `concat`.

```
var through = require('through');

// create a stream that reads gulp File objects and outputs their contents
function sendTo(res) {   
    return through(
        function write(data) {    // this will be called once for each file
            res.write(data.contents);
        },
        function end() {    // this will be called when there are no more files
            res.end()
        }
    );
}

app.get('/app/js/concatenated-js-files.js', function(req, res){
    gulp.src('app/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(sendTo(res));
});
```

Also, `gulp` internally uses `vinyl-fs` to read the files, so you can use vinyl-fs directly if have no other need for `gulp`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is part of me learning to work with streams so I wouldn't mind not using gulp but the way it selects files using minimap and allowing an array of minimap selectors is very convenient. AFAIK Glob doesn't let me do that. But thanks! this is great.