# How do I serve concatenated Javascript files with Gulp?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-concat

I'm trying to concat a few JS files and serve them as a single file with Gulp. I'd like to do this without writing to the filesystem.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  connect.server();

  gulp.src('*.js')
    .pipe(concat("assets.js"))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

But this doesn't work. When I try accessing `http://localhost:8080/assets.js`, it says that it's not found.

How do I go about achieving this? I am also ok with using another plugin instead of `gulp-connect` if that works.

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791136/piping-concatenated-gulp-stream-file-contents-to-server-connect-express-or-htt

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to specify `gulp.dest`. An example from the `gulp-concat` module:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./lib/file3.js', './lib/file1.js', './lib/file2.js'])
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Comment: Does `gulp.dest` write to the file system? I've stated in the question that "I'd like to do this without writing to the filesystem."

Comment: It writes to the file system so node.js scripts run from files.